# what are the ways in which i can update a single node on basis of ID in C#2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

This code below is not working on server.I am trying to update a child node on basis of id..Code as follows.

This code is working fine locally but not working on server.please let me know if I am doing any mistake in the below code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DateData.Length - 1; i++)
                {

              XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
              string filepathsUpdate = Server.MapPath("Contact.xml");
              xmlDoc.Load(filepathsUpdate);
              XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + DateData[i] + "]/Status");
              node.InnerText = "Request Completed";
              xmlDoc.Save(filepathsUpdate);

            }
```

I their any other way I can update the status node on basis of id.This code is working on C#2.0 which is framework 2.0...in net.

Comment: Define "not working" on server?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Sidenote: **For each entry** in DateData you create an XmlDoc, load it from Disk, modify its contents and save it ... while the only part that depends on the DateData[i] is one line ... ok actually 2.

Comment: `i < DateData.Length - 1;` Do you intentionally omit the last entry?

Comment: yes I intentionally do as last index of the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that it's this

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + DateData[i] + "]/Status");
```

Maybe should be this instead

```
var xpath = String.Format(@"/CATALOG/CD[ID=""{0}""]/Status", DateData[i]);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Or maybe even this, depending on the data type of `DateData`.

```
var xpath = String.Format(@"/CATALOG/CD[ID=""{0}""]/Status", DateData[i].ToString("SOME_OBSCURE_FORMAT_STRING"));
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```